# Vertical space every third row in a table

Tags: tables, spacing

I have the following code to put an extra space (a carriage return) after every second row. How can I edit the code to put the extra space after every third row instead?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}

\begin{tabular*}{1\textwidth}{@{
\global\let\restorecr=\\ 
\extracolsep{\fill} } c *{4}{c}}
\toprule

\global\let\oldcr=\\ 
\global\def\crsng{\global\let\\ =\crdbl\oldcr}
\global\def\crdbl{\global\let\\ =\crsng\oldcr[40pt]}
\global\let\\=\crdbl

& \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Panel A}}\\ 
\midrule
a & 0.55 & 0.66 & 0.64 & 0.64 \\
  & 0.55 & 0.66 & 0.64 & 0.64 \\ 
  & 0.55 & 0.66 & 0.64 & 0.64 \\
a & 0.55 & 0.66 & 0.64 & 0.64 \\ 
  & 0.55 & 0.66 & 0.64 & 0.64 \\
  & 0.55 & 0.66 & 0.64 & 0.64 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\global\let\\ =\restorecr

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: If I add more panels of data the solution proposed below no longer works.

```
&\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{All Data}}\tabularnewline     
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Panel A}}\tabularnewline 
\midrule
a & 0.55 & 0.66 & 0.64 & 0.64 \\
  & 0.55 & 0.66 & 0.64 & 0.64 \\ 
  & 0.55 & 0.66 & 0.64 & 0.64 \\
a & 0.55 & 0.66 & 0.64 & 0.64 \\ 
a & 0.55 & 0.66 & 0.64 & 0.64 \\
  & 0.55 & 0.66 & 0.64 & 0.64 \\ 
    & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Panel B}}\tabularnewline
\midrule
a & 0.55 & 0.66 & 0.64 & 0.64 \\
  & 0.55 & 0.66 & 0.64 & 0.64 \\ 
  & 0.55 & 0.66 & 0.64 & 0.64 \\
a & 0.55 & 0.66 & 0.64 & 0.64 \\ 
a & 0.55 & 0.66 & 0.64 & 0.64 \\
  & 0.55 & 0.66 & 0.64 & 0.64 \\ 
    & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Panel C}}\tabularnewline 
\midrule
a & 0.55 & 0.66 & 0.64 & 0.64 \\
  & 0.55 & 0.66 & 0.64 & 0.64 \\ 
  & 0.55 & 0.66 & 0.64 & 0.64 \\
a & 0.55 & 0.66 & 0.64 & 0.64 \\ 
a & 0.55 & 0.66 & 0.64 & 0.64 \\
  & 0.55 & 0.66 & 0.64 & 0.64 \\
```

Comment: Note that ``\global\let\\=\restorecr`` is a mistake, because ``\\`` has different meanings inside a tabular than outside.

Comment: It seems that a workaround for this new edit is to replace the second \tabularnewline at top with \vspace{-1.5cm}\\. Then the result will show what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution does not understand the mechanism behind the code (not up to par anyway), but based on the given code for inserting vertical space for every second row, this solution found the logic behind it and this is how this solution is generated here.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}

\begin{tabular*}{1\textwidth}{@{
\global\let\restorecr=\\ 
\extracolsep{\fill} } c *{4}{c}}
\toprule

%\global\let\oldcr=\\ 
%\global\def\crsng{\global\let\\ =\crdbl\oldcr}
%\global\def\crdbl{\global\let\\ =\crsng\oldcr[40pt]}
%\global\let\\=\crdbl

\global\let\oldcr=\\ 
\global\def\crsng{\global\let\\ =\crtri\oldcr}
\global\def\crdbl{\global\let\\ =\crsng\oldcr}
\global\def\crtri{\global\let\\ =\crdbl\oldcr[40pt]}
\global\let\\=\crtri

& \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Panel A}}\\ 
\midrule
a & 0.55 & 0.66 & 0.64 & 0.64 \\
  & 0.55 & 0.66 & 0.64 & 0.64 \\ 
  & 0.55 & 0.66 & 0.64 & 0.64 \\
a & 0.55 & 0.66 & 0.64 & 0.64 \\ 
  & 0.55 & 0.66 & 0.64 & 0.64 \\
  & 0.55 & 0.66 & 0.64 & 0.64 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\global\let\\ =\restorecr

\end{table}
```

Comment: That solution is helpful, but is there any way to avoid the pattern of spacing every three lines being applied to the `& \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Panel A}}\\' statement? I want to apply it only to every third row in each panel. I'll add an edit to the question.

Comment: I tried \vspace{-1.5cm} right before \multicolumn can reduce the gap.